# Delete based on BSON date attribute?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to do a conditional remove in Mongo based on an attribute of a BSON date?  I'm trying to do this:

```
db.events.remove( { StartTime.getDay() : { $ne : "1" } } )
```

I know I could copy the day into a new attribute but I have over 7 million records and I'd prefer to evaluate this 'in-line' if possible.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me (p.s. this is my first day using mongo).  As sample document looks like:

```
> db.events.findOne()
{
..
"_id" : ObjectId("53f4fceeec3ef1e91d997d8d"),
"StartTime" : ISODate("2014-07-22T04:59:52Z") 
..
}
```

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) query form which operates on JavaScript evaluation. It is a valid form of query but naturally cannot use an index as the evaluation is in JavaScript code.

```js
db.collection.remove(function() { return this.StartTime.getDay() != 1 });
```

That is a shorthand form for `$where` which has a longer form for combination with other operators:

```js
db.collection.remove({ "$where": function() { return this.StartTime.getDay() != 1 } });
```

For the shell it can just be a code object, for other languages it is typically a string.

Comment: Thank you for your help Neil.  I am actually running into a similar problem.  I cannot select on the this.StartTime.getDay().  Your example only selects on this.StartTime.  I basically want to delete any document that has a day that is not the first of the month.

Comment: Here is a GIST of what I am trying to do: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/223cd8ad61f26e366285

Comment: @dps It was a typo. I meant to call the function which is the point. You do this with JavaScript evaluation as there are no built in operators outside of the aggregation framework. Which of course does not remove matched documents.

Comment: Neil Lunn, thank you sir.  This worked.  db.events.remove( { $where: function() { return (this.StartTime.getDay() == this.StartTime.getDay()) } } );